# Managing UI animation visible over a SpriteKit scene

Tags: swift, multithreading, sprite-kit

I'm currently having issues attempting to have a draggable UI element partly covering a SpriteKit Scene. When using the Pan gesture to update the location of the UI element that is displayed onto of the scene, the SpriteKit scene in the background starts to lose frames and become jumpy. I believe both of this operations are being run on the Main thread as they are required for the UI to appear smooth. Is it possible to manage both of these simultaneously without causing the SpriteKit scene become jumpy?

Comment: Check that both elements have different zPosition. that generates a strange jumpy effect. I can't imagine more without code or examples.

Comment: The UI element is above the entire SpriteKit scene on the Storyboard. Will get an example to show you.